# How can I determine the length of a std::string which contains "\0" in its middle?

Tags: c++, string, terminator

I am writing a C++ application which receives an input from a socket. This input comes as a rawdata string and so, it contains lots of "\0" in its body.

My question is, how can I determine its length/size without stoping at the "\0"s, so I would be able read the complete socket response? The response itsef is 148 long, but the size() retuns 2.

Comment: Doesn't the functions you're using return the actual number of bytes received? `how can I determine its length/size without stoping at the "\0"s` You should never use this technique, even if you had null terminated strings being sent. Use the return value that is sent back to you to determine the length.

Comment: `std::string` has an appropriate constructor for a C string with a size.

Comment: Use a std::string (std::vector<char>) as buffer or pass the C-string and the size to further processing (hard to answer without code)

Comment: I'm going to go against the curve and say that by definition, std::string is a 0 terminated string. If you have a \0, than you have multiple "std::strings" in the buffer. You should be using a different datastructure, most likelye std::vector<char> (and use foo.data() to get the c-string char*)

Comment: @MadScienceDreams sadly `std::string` beg to differ with that definition :)

Comment: @MadScienceDreams By definition: std::string does not care about any '\0' in the middle.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: You might be thinking of a c-string (`char*`), rather than the C++ `std::string` class, which can very much store 0s, no problem.

Comment: @DieterLücking : I used a vector as you suggested and it did the trick. Thank you! thank you to all you guys too, I also didn't know about this string constructor with a size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`size()` returns the actual length of the string and does not consider null bytes to end the string. The reason you're getting a size of two is because there are different ways to set the string's value and some of them *do* consider null bytes to be the string terminator. So you've mistakenly set the value of the string to be a string of two characters rather than set it to hold the complete response data, and `size()` is accurately reflecting that mistake.

The solution is to initialize or set the string using a method that does not consider null bytes:

```
char buffer[] = "abcd\0efg";

std::string s(buffer, 8);
std::cout << s.size() << '\n'; // outputs "8"

std::string s2(buffer);
std::cout << s2.size() << '\n'; // outputs "4"
```

Comment: I will assume this as the answer because it does explain what I asked. But my real problem was the char* buffer I was using and my lack of knowledge about C++. While debugging I couldn't see the value of the hexstring. I changed the buffer to a vector<char> and processed the bytes to hexstring with no problem, thx @dieter-lucking